# Помогите оптимизировать алгоритм нахождения делителей

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def divider(number):
    pol = [1, number]
    number1 = number
    dividers = [2, 3, 5, 7]
    for i in range(2, number1 + 1):
        if number1 % i == 0:
            if pol.count(i) < 1:
                pol.append(i)
                number1 /= i
            else:
                pass
            for j in dividers:
                u = i * j
                if number % u == 0 and pol.count(u) < 1:
                    if i * j == number:
                        pass
                    else:
                        pol.append(u)
    print(sorted(pol))
```

Задумка в том, чтобы когда делитель был найден, программа делила на него число, тем самым, она работала бы быстрее. Но строчка number1 /= i только все портит, так как некоторая часть делителей просто не находится и также не изменяет значение nimber1 в цикле. Помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: В качестве делителей должны проверяться только числа из dividers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce


def sieve_of_eratosthenes(n): 
    is_prime = 2 * [False] + (n-1) * [True]
    p = 2
    while (p * p <= n): 
        if is_prime[p]: 
            for i in range(2 * p, n + 1, p): 
                is_prime[i] = False
        p += 1
    return is_prime


def all_prime_factors(n):
    is_prime = sieve_of_eratosthenes(n)
    prime_facts = [i for i in range(n + 1) if is_prime[i] and n % i == 0]
    prime_facts_powers = []
    for p in prime_facts:
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            if n % p**i:
                break
        prime_facts_powers.append(i - 1)
    return prime_facts, prime_facts_powers, len(prime_facts)


def all_divisors(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    primes, powers, nfactors = all_prime_factors(n)
    exponents = nfactors * [0]
    divisors = []
    while True:
        factors = [primes[x] ** exponents[x] for x in range(nfactors)]
        divisor = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, factors, 1)
        divisors.append(divisor)
        i = 0
        while True:
            exponents[i] += 1
            if exponents[i] <= powers[i]:
                break
            exponents[i] = 0
            i += 1
            if i >= nfactors:
                return divisors
```

---

Тест:

```
all_divisors(24)
```

> ```
> [1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 24]
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Разложим число на простые множители и создаем все комбинации этих простых множителей.

Пример: Число 24.

Разложение: `24 = 2**3 * 3**1`

Возможные степени 2: `2**0`, `2**1`, `2**2`, `2**3`
Возможные степени 3: `3**0`, `3**1`

Делители:
`2**0 * 3**0`  1
`2**1 * 3**0`  2
`2**2 * 3**0`  4
`2**3 * 3**0`  8
`2**0 * 3**1`  3
`2**1 * 3**1`  6
`2**2 * 3**1`  12
`2**3 * 3**1`  24

Answer (score 2):

Вот самый быстрый вариант

```
import math


def find_all_divisors(x):
       div_list = set()
       for y in range(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
           if x % y == 0:
               div_list.add(y)
               div_list.add(x // y)
       return [i for i in div_list]


print(find_all_divisors(40))
```

Comment: Вместо `int(x / y)` возможно просто `x // y`.

Comment: Вместо `y = 1 while y <= math.sqrt(x): ..... y += 1` более питoнически: `for y in range(1, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n))) + 1):`.....

Comment: Ошибка - name 'divList' is not defined.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! А почему нужно сравнивать именно с квадратным корнем?

Comment: Для квадратов натуральных чисел `(x = 1, 4, 9, ...)` будут в результате дубликаты.

Comment: @8oDolaz допустим у числа есть делитель а. Тогда пусть b=x/a. b тоже является делителем. Несложно догадаться, что или а или b не превосходят квадратный корень. Поэтому делаю for до квадратного корня мы находим один из пары a, b. а соответственно вычисляем и второй

Comment: Вместо `return [i for i in div_list]` просто `return list(div_list)` и будет всё в порядке. +1.

Comment: raw, просто спасибо огромное. После объяснения стало понятно.

Comment: `div_list` не очень хорошее имя для **множества**, лучше было бы `div_set`.

Comment: `return sorted(div_list)` (вместо `return [i for i in div_list]`) бы возвращало более полезный, **упорядоченный** список.